# Doubt in a commutator relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

There is a proof in *J.J Sakurai Mordern Quantum Mechanics* page 30 which says

> Suppose that A and B are compatible observables, and the
> eigenvalues of A are nondegenerate. Then the matrix elements $\langle a''|B|a'\rangle$ are all diagonal.

In the proof he says that

> $\langle a''|[A,B]|a'\rangle = (a''-a')\langle a''|B|a'\rangle$

I am not able to understand how LHS implies RHS
My attempt:
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle a''|[A,B]|a'\rangle = \langle a''|AB - BA|a'\rangle\\
\end{eqnarray}
Now since $|a'\rangle$ is eigenket of A,
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle a''|[A,B]|a'\rangle &=& \langle a''|AB - a' B|a'\rangle \\
&=&  \langle a''|(A - a' I) B|a'\rangle
\end{eqnarray}
I don't understand what to do next in order to get the required equation

Comment: Hint: Given that $\vert a''\rangle$ is an eigenket with eigenvalue $a''$ of the operator $A$, what would be an eigenbra with eigenvalue $a''$ of the operator $A^\dagger = A$? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes something like this:
$$\langle a''|[A,B]|a'\rangle =\langle a''|AB-BA|a'\rangle =\langle a''|AB|a'\rangle -\langle a''|BA|a'\rangle =a''\langle a''|B|a'\rangle -a'\langle a''|B|a'\rangle =(a''-a')\langle a''|B|a'\rangle $$
Here we have considered the operator to be Hermitian.

---

It is used:
$$A|a'\rangle  =a'|a'\rangle \ \ \ \langle  a'|A=a'\langle a'|$$